# A word to describe having good command of the English language?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe having good command of the English language? The kind of word that could be listed as an attribute?

Comment: General Reference - [fluent, articulate, eloquent](http://thesaurus.com/browse/eloquent) etc.

Comment: Doh... brain fart I guess.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Not exactly the easiest thing to Google, unless you already know the words.

Comment: Yes, maybe this is a poor question or a poorly phrased one, but I disagree with the fact that that is general reference,

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I can't disagree - it's an awkward issue. But despite the fact the proposal for [English Language Learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) has been turned down, ELU's FAQ still says this site is [for **(serious)** English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq). I think anyone who fits that definition should know at least one of the words I listed (or an equivalent), and should thus be able to find more by just googling *"synonym"* plus whatever they *do* know.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, due to divine intervention, the [ELL proposal has been re-opened](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners).

Comment: @tchrist "divine intervention"? Could you please be more precise. Since I'm agnostic, I do not believe in miracles and, however, I was thought that God never does what others can do.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already thought to "mastery" ("n. Full command of a subject of study: Her mastery of economic theory impressed the professors. n. Expert knowledge or skill; power of using or exercising; dexterity: as, the mastery of an art or science.")?

Reading the above definitions, it seems you could say something like this: "Do you have mastery of English language?" or "Her mastery of English language impressed the professors."

Answer (score 0):

There is not a unique word to describe this. If the person only has a *good* command of English, the simplest is "functional in English". If that is not strong enough, go with "fluent".